# ChromeOS won't update

Tags: upgrade, software-updates, chrome-os

This is the error code: I'm not sure what it means or what to do. I'm on a ChromeOS laptop

```
---- START OF UPGRADE ----
+ grep -q VERSION_CODENAME=stretch /etc/os-release
+ export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
+ APT_KEY_DONT_WARN_ON_DANGEROUS_USAGE=1 apt-key adv --batch --refresh-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com EB4C1BFD4F042F6DDDCCEC917721F63BD38B4796
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.vYTyKq8BN7/gpg.1.sh --batch --refresh-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com EB4C1BFD4F042F6DDDCCEC917721F63BD38B4796
gpg: refreshing 1 key from hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 7721F63BD38B4796: "Google Inc. (Linux Packages Signing Authority) <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
+ do_upgrade
+ APT_OPTIONS=-o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef
   -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold
+ dpkg --configure -a
+ apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold update -y --allow-releaseinfo-change
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt/ xenial: /usr/share/keyrings/signal-desktop-keyring.gpg != 
E: The list of sources could not be read.
---- START OF UPGRADE ----
+ grep -q VERSION_CODENAME=stretch /etc/os-release
+ export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
+ APT_KEY_DONT_WARN_ON_DANGEROUS_USAGE=1 apt-key adv --batch --refresh-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com EB4C1BFD4F042F6DDDCCEC917721F63BD38B4796
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.jwXFtjvLZ0/gpg.1.sh --batch --refresh-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com EB4C1BFD4F042F6DDDCCEC917721F63BD38B4796
gpg: refreshing 1 key from hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 7721F63BD38B4796: "Google Inc. (Linux Packages Signing Authority) <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
+ do_upgrade
+ APT_OPTIONS=-o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef
   -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold
+ dpkg --configure -a
+ apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold update -y --allow-releaseinfo-change
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt/ xenial: /usr/share/keyrings/signal-desktop-keyring.gpg != 
E: The list of sources could not be read.
---- START OF UPGRADE ----
+ grep -q VERSION_CODENAME=stretch /etc/os-release
+ export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
+ APT_KEY_DONT_WARN_ON_DANGEROUS_USAGE=1 apt-key adv --batch --refresh-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com EB4C1BFD4F042F6DDDCCEC917721F63BD38B4796
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.HyYSLmZdq6/gpg.1.sh --batch --refresh-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com EB4C1BFD4F042F6DDDCCEC917721F63BD38B4796
gpg: refreshing 1 key from hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 7721F63BD38B4796: "Google Inc. (Linux Packages Signing Authority) <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
+ do_upgrade
+ APT_OPTIONS=-o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef
   -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold
+ dpkg --configure -a
+ apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold update -y --allow-releaseinfo-change
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt/ xenial: /usr/share/keyrings/signal-desktop-keyring.gpg != 
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Comment: What's in `/etc/sources.list` and/or `/etc/sources.list.d/*`?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list
```

Ref [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1329200/unable-to-download-signal-desktop-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-please-help).